# How to I stop a launchd script from running on wake

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, launchd

I have a simple launchd script that plays a sound every 30 minutes and it runs out of the user library `~/Library` . It doesn't run if my machine is asleep, but does run the last event missed when the machine wakes. I think this is the expected behavior. My question is, how do I stop this happening. If I missed the half-hour event, I don't want it to be run at 20 minutes past the hour.

Here's the core of my script. It calls a Python script. I tried to put a block in the python script to check that I am within a few minutes of each 30 minutes, but that doesn't seem to work on wake. (Is it missing the system clock somehow?)

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
    <string>/Users/pheon/Documents/playsound.py</string>
</array>

<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here is a snippet from the python code which checks the time before playing the sound.

`time0 = datetime.datetime.now()
if (time0.minute % 30) < 2:
    subprocess.run(["/Users/pheon/bin/afplay-vol.sh", "1", bell],check=True)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem lies with launchd and how it handles jobs that are missed during sleep:

From the `launchd.plist` man page (`man launchd.plist`)

> ```
> Unlike cron which skips job invocations when the computer is asleep,
> launchd will start the job the next time the computer wakes up.  If
> multiple intervals transpire before the computer is woken, those
> events will be coalesced into one event upon wake from sleep.
> ```

So, there are a few options to consider...

- revert to `cron`.  Though deprecated, `cron` won't run jobs that have been missed
- check for time of day before playing the sound (this can be done with a "wrapper" script or within the script itself.
- write a log entry (somewhere).  On script launch, parse the log.  If a sound was played within the last 30 mins, don't play again.

Comment: After some effort playing with launchd, I have reverted to cron. There were some issues getting cron to work on Mohave. I used advice from here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781884/is-crontab-broken-on-osx-el-capitan/42687254?noredirect=1#comment94933580_42687254]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and addressed it by using a shell conditional evaluation:

```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>zsh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>minute=$(date +"%M");   if [[ $minute = 00 || $minute = 30 ]]; then afplay -v 2 /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff; fi</string>
  </array>
```